# Right to Left div and hide after 5 sec using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am displaying div from right to left and after 5 sec it will hide. I tried some code right to left is working but after 5 sec it's not hiding.

I tried `opacity:0` inside keyframe but then my animation not working.

Would you help me out in this?

```css
.successAlet {
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 400px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1001;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInRight;
  animation-name: fadeInRight;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="successAlet">
  <h2>Animate and then autohide in 5 sec</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a second animation. You can also simplify your code by removing a lot of non needed properties

```css
.successAlet {
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 400px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1001;
  animation-name: fadeInRight,hide;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 0s,3s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}



@keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes hide {
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="successAlet">
  <h2>Animate and then autohide in 5 sec</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh! Yes, It's working. I never know we can use the second animation. Thanks for the help. Upvote from my side.

Answer (score 0):

for smooth hide

```
@keyframes hide {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 0;
  }
}
```